# dnd-kit sortable animation is triggering twice on DragEnd

Tags: reactjs, animation, drag-and-drop, transform, dnd-kit

When I swap two distant items on a grid it 'redoes' the swap animation (going backwards then forwards again). It works fine when the items are very near as you can see in the following gif:
[image]

I've followed the [Sortable docs](https://docs.dndkit.com/presets/sortable) but I can't figure out why it is redoing the animation. I just want to drop it on the grid cell and keep the old item on the position it already is, not doing the animation over again

[Here's the link to the code sample](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dnd-kit-twice-animation-qc6h52)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently I solved it setting `animateLayoutChanges: () => false` on the `useSortable` hook

Answer (score 2):

```
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition } =
    useSortable({
      id: image,
      transition: {
        duration: 500,
        easing: "cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1)",
      },
    });
```

This is a better solution I found because animateLayoutChanges: () => false sets all the transition to false.